# how attach the relationship when getting data from database by model in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I want to attach the relationship when getting data from database by model in laravel.
I use these code to do this.
but I know there is better way to do this.

thanks for your helps.

```
$courses = Cource::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->take($count)->get();
 foreach($courses as $cource){
        $cource['image'] =  $cource->image()->get();
        $cource['rate'] = $cource->rate()->get();
}
```

Comment: The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) is probably the first place to look for questions like these. Laravel has a **ton** of built in functionality. So if you're thinking there should be a better way to accomplish something, first check the docs; there may already be a built in way (like eager loading).

Comment: thanks for your guid.
I read document and I understand that with ( ) is not working for morph relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `with`:

```
$courses = Cource::orderBy('id' , 'desc')
    ->take($count)
    ->with(['image', 'rate'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I forgot that say I use it later but don't work and give me the empty array.

Comment: `give me the empty array` when this happens? when you serialize them? when you try to access them? or what?..

Comment: I think that is  not working due to I use morph relationship and I wanted to use with( ) for this  .

Comment: try with `protected $with = ['image', 'rate'];` on the model class

Answer (score 0):

```
$courses = Cource::orderBy('id' , 'desc')
->take($count)
->with(['image', 'rate'])
->get();
```

the condition is that use all relationship except `morph relationship`